# postgres automatic table list partitioning

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

How to handle new partitions in a smart automatic manner in PostgreSQL ?

I want to create a PostgreSQL table List partition on a certain column.
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
  id            int ,
  country_code  VARCHAR,
  order_total   int,
  CONSTRAINT orders_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
) PARTITION BY LIST (country_code)
```

however I dont know all the possible counties in advance, on an oracle table I will enable auto partitioning:

```
ALTER TABLE orders SET PARTITIONING AUTOMATIC;
```

It seems like PostgreSQL lacks this feature, I have read that I can add a default partition to the table and then <s>later on add another partition and the values from the default partition would be transferred automatically to the new partition</s>. (**EDIT**: default partition block you from creating new partitions if you previously inserted values to it)

what would be the best strategy to handle this in an automatic manner ? Are there any plans to add this feature to PostgreSQL?

Comment: I have created an external script as adding a trigger before/update on the default partition would slow down the insertion. So the script runs every month as I have partitioned for each month and then it checks the records which are there in default partition.I admit there are many steps to ensure. I wish it would have been easier but it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't heard of any plans to add such a feature.

You can easily create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that creates partitions on demand, but of course that trigger has to run for each row inserted, which means a certain performance impact.

Using a default partition like you suggest is a solution with better performance, but it requires later explicitly moving the data to a different partition, which can be painful.

If you expect new countries to pop up all the time, maybe the trigger is the way to go. If it happens once in a blue moon, I might prefer the second way.